# How to add a second SSH key?

Tags: shell, ssh, sh, centos7, ssh-keys

I already have an SSH key, it is I use it with GitHub, but they have provided me with another one to enter a server on AWS, a RedHat 7.

It was actually a .ppk to use with PuTTY, but with the generator I converted it to an SSH key.

I have added it and it worked correctly, the problem is that every time I want to use it I have to add it again, and I don't know why I forgot it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to add it again

It depends by what you mean by "add it".

- If it is `ssh-agent add`, you only need to do that when the private key is passphrase protected.
- if it is "adding to the remote server ~/.ssh/authorized_keys", you only need to do that once, with the public key associated to/derived from the private key.